# quality of eps figure in pdf file

Tags: graphics, pdf, eps, ps

I want to plot colorful `*.eps` files in the pdf file.

However, colorful figures have white meshes in the pdf file that the figures in the ps file do not have.

Can I plot the colorful figures in the pdf file as clear as in the ps file?

I compile the text file into pdf by `tex->dvi->ps->pdf` with following commands.

```
latex A.tex
dvips A.dvi
ps2pdf -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode A.ps
```

[image: figure in the ps file]
[image: figure in the pdf file]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with `{}` on it).

Comment: The white lines are probably a result of the conversion from vector to raster for display by your PDF viewer.  They will not be present in a printed copy.  Also, if you convert to a raster format, they will not be visible.

Comment: Also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238547/eps-images-come-with-ugly-grid

Comment: What pdf viewer are you using? I usually have the same problem with `Preview` but with `acrobat` it looks fine.

Comment: Another thing for testing such issues, is to zoom in. Then you'll often know if it is an issue with the previewer.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. By the way, when I opened the pdf file with GNU Image Manipulation Program, there still exists white grids. I suspect that conversion from vector to raster happens by the time I compile them from ps to pdf. 

@James I cannot print out the figure right now. But I'll check it out later. Thanks.

Comment: If you have `Imagemagick` installed, convert the `eps` to `png` using this command and see if the `png` has the grid.  `convert -density 300x300 filename.eps filename.png`

Comment: yes it has the white grid in the png file.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't expect that.  I don't know if I can help, but I'd like to have a copy of your `eps` file to play with.  Can you make it available online somewhere?

Comment: @James I uploaded the eps file at

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_KZXBoctczHdWZPOU0ydDdhNms/view?usp=sharing

Comment: A related question is here... http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238547/eps-images-come-with-ugly-grid

Answer (score 1):

I've played with the `EPS` file you linked in the comment above.  As you said, after conversion the white grid is showing up in the `PDF` and even in the `PNG` after using

```
convert -density 300x300 branin.eps branin.png
```

The only thing I know to get rid of the grid is to convert to a very high resolution `PNG` and then scale the `PNG` down.  The white grid gets averaged into the surrounding colors during the scaling.  These commands might take a few minutes depending on your processor speed.  Depending on your operating system, you might need to replace `%` with `%%` in the second command.

```
convert -density 2400x2400 branin.eps braninTemp.png
convert -scale 10% braninTemp.png branin.png
```

Of course the downside of this process is that you are left with a raster image instead of a vector image.  Here's a view of the resulting `branin.png`.

[image]

Another option that you apparently are aware of is to take a screen shot of the `EPS` file in whatever viewer you used to generate the image in your question.